# getActivity().getFragmentManager() v/s fragment.getFragmentManager()

Tags: android

I really confused between these two combinations by means doing

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager()
```

and

```
fragment.getFragmentManager()
```

as if we see the inner implementation the Activity.java has

```
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
        return mFragments.getFragmentManager();
    }
```

while Fragment.java has

```
 final public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
        return mFragmentManager;
    }
```

does it mean we have always different FragmentManager or else?

Comment: Read the code comments? https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#L743-L753

Answer (score 1):

A Fragment is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity. Interaction with fragments is done through FragmentManager, which can be obtained via **`Activity.getFragmentManager()`** and **`Fragment.getFragmentManager()`**.

**[getActivity().getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager())**

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this activity.

**[fragment.getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager())**

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this fragment's activity. Note that this will be non-null
>   slightly before getActivity(), during the time from when the fragment
>   is placed in a FragmentTransaction until it is committed and attached
>   to its activity.
>
> If this Fragment is a child of another Fragment, the FragmentManager
>   returned here will be the parent's **[getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())**.